# Magento 2 - Minicart display subtotals incl. tax

Tags: checkout, magento2, mini-cart

When I adjust the option in Magento to display subtotals including tax the minicart breaks. I get this error in my console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "if: function (){return displaySubtotal() }"
Message: Unable to process binding "if: function (){return !display_cart_subtotal_excl_tax && display_subtotal_incl_tax }"
Message: display_subtotal_incl_tax is not defined
```

Does anyone have the same issue?

Comment: I get this also, tried changing the themes but the error is there everytime. Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I did not resolve this issue. It's still open.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3102

A fix has been committed: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/eec3cf17bc5deae71c83c797d1339de46cf6905f#diff-5a9e548214bfe6e296f0f1473d4e9136

So a workaround until fix is released is to override the `vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/minicart/subtotal/totals.html` template and replace `display_subtotal_incl_tax` with `display_cart_subtotal_incl_tax`.